# MongoDB Node.JS driver: create, append, and update documents with arrays

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, crud

I am looking to achieve the following operations with the MongoDB Node.JS driver, could this be performed with an optimal approach? There are three possible operations required: create, append, and update.

1. Create the following document.

```
{
    "_id": "hello_world_cluster",
        "items": [
            {
                "item_name": "my_item_one",
                "first_seen": 1000,
                "last_seen": 1000,
                "logic": true
            }
        ]
}
```

2. Append new items to an array.

```
{
    "_id": "hello_world_cluster",
        "items": [
            {
                "item_name": "my_item_one",
                "first_seen": 1000,
                "last_seen": 1000,
                "logic": true
            },
            {
                "item_name": "my_item_two",
                "first_seen": 2000,
                "last_seen": 2000,
                "logic": true
            },
            {
                "item_name": "my_item_three",
                "first_seen": 3000,
                "last_seen": 3000,
                "logic": true
            }
        ]
}
```

3. Update items that are found in an array.

```
{
    "_id": "hello_world_cluster",
        "items": [
            {
                "item_name": "my_item_one",
                "first_seen": 1000,
                "last_seen": 4000,
                "logic": false
            },
            {
                "item_name": "my_item_two",
                "first_seen": 2000,
                "last_seen": 2000,
                "logic": true
            },
            {
                "item_name": "my_item_three",
                "first_seen": 3000,
                "last_seen": 3000,
                "logic": true
            }
        ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I drafted some sample code for you:

```js
const { MongoClient } = require('mongodb');

async function main() {
    /**
     * Connection URI. Update <username>, <password>, and <your-cluster-url> to reflect your cluster.
     */
    const uri = "mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>@<your-cluster-url>/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority";

    /**
     * The Mongo Client you will use to interact with your database
     */
    const client = new MongoClient(uri, { useUnifiedTopology: true });

    try {
        // Connect to the MongoDB cluster
        await client.connect();

        // Make the appropriate DB calls

        // Create a new document
        await createDocument(client);

        // Append new items to the items array
        await appendNewItemsToArray(client);

        // Update items in the items array
        await updateItemsInArray(client);


    } finally {
        // Close the connection to the MongoDB cluster
        await client.close();
    }
}

main().catch(console.error);

async function createDocument(client) {
    const result = await client.db("NameOfYourDb").collection("NameOfYourCollection").insertOne({
        "_id": "UniqueId1",
        "items": [
            {
                "item_name": "my_item_one",
                "first_seen": 1000,
                "last_seen": 1000,
                "logic": true
            }
        ]
    });
    console.log(`New document created with the following id: ${result.insertedId}`);
}

async function appendNewItemsToArray(client) {
    const result = await client.db("NameOfYourDb").collection("NameOfYourCollection").updateOne(
        { "_id": "UniqueId1" },
        {
            $push: {
                items: {
                    $each: [
                        {
                            "item_name": "my_item_two",
                            "first_seen": 2000,
                            "last_seen": 2000,
                            "logic": true
                        },
                        {
                            "item_name": "my_item_three",
                            "first_seen": 3000,
                            "last_seen": 3000,
                            "logic": true
                        }]
                }
            }
        });

    console.log(`${result.matchedCount} document(s) matched the query criteria.`);
    console.log(`${result.modifiedCount} document(s) was/were updated.`);
}

async function updateItemsInArray(client) {
    const result = await client.db("NameOfYourDb").collection("NameOfYourCollection").updateOne(
        { "_id": "UniqueId1", "items.item_name": "my_item_one" },
        { $set: { "items.$.logic": false, "items.$.last_seen": 4000 } }
    );

    console.log(`${result.matchedCount} document(s) matched the query criteria.`);
    console.log(`${result.modifiedCount} document(s) was/were updated.`);
}
```

One important thing to note:  The _id needs to be unique for every document within a collection.  You do not have to manually create the _id.  If you omit _id from the document, the driver will automatically create one for you.

This code is based on code from my blog series.  Some helpful links for you:

- https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/quick-start-nodejs-mongodb--how-to-get-connected-to-your-database

  - https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/quick-start-nodejs--mongodb--how-to-create-documents
  - https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/quick-start-nodejs--mongodb--how-to-update-documents

The code takes advantage of combining $push and $each.  See https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/#example-push-each for more details on that.

The code also takes advantage of the positional $ operator.  See https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/ for more details on that.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful piece of marvelous code; This has helped me understand the driver better. Although I am having another issue, I suppose we should use 'findOneAndUpdate' with 'upsert: true' for updating existing documents? If else: 'E11000 duplicate key error collection: NameOfYourDb.NameOfYourCollection index: _id_ dup key: { : "UniqueId1" }' 
The idea is that I do not control the incoming new documents, they have to be created if they have to, else they got to be updated (or have their arrays appended with new items).

Comment: If you want to insert a document if it does not exist or update it if it does exist, you should use upsert.

Note that you can use findOneAndUpdate if you want the document to be returned as part of the result.  Otherwise, you can use updateOne.