# MongoDB Node.JS driver: create, append, and update documents with arrays in one go

Tags: javascript, mongodb

Is this really the only way to create, append, and update documents with arrays in a database or could this be done in only ONE beautiful operation ? I am of course looking to optimise this bit of code into how it is supposed to be implemented in MongoDB operators, it would reduce the operations done to the database... What do you think?

```
const { MongoClient } = require('mongodb');

async function main() {

    try {

        // Make the appropriate DB calls

        // Create a new document
        await createDocument(client);

        // Append new items to the items array
        await appendNewItemsToArray(client);

        // Update items in the items array
        await updateItemsInArray(client);


    } finally {
        // Close the connection to the MongoDB cluster
        await client.close();
    }
}

main().catch(console.error);

async function createDocument(client) {
    const result = await client.db("NameOfYourDb").collection("NameOfYourCollection").insertOne({
        "_id": "UniqueId1",
        "items": [
            {
                "item_name": "my_item_one",
                "first_seen": 1000,
                "last_seen": 1000,
                "logic": true
            }
        ]
    });
    console.log(`New document created with the following id: ${result.insertedId}`);
}

async function appendNewItemsToArray(client) {
    const result = await client.db("NameOfYourDb").collection("NameOfYourCollection").updateOne(
        { "_id": "UniqueId1" },
        {
            $push: {
                items: {
                    $each: [
                        {
                            "item_name": "my_item_two",
                            "first_seen": 2000,
                            "last_seen": 2000,
                            "logic": true
                        },
                        {
                            "item_name": "my_item_three",
                            "first_seen": 3000,
                            "last_seen": 3000,
                            "logic": true
                        }]
                }
            }
        });

    console.log(`${result.matchedCount} document(s) matched the query criteria.`);
    console.log(`${result.modifiedCount} document(s) was/were updated.`);
}

async function updateItemsInArray(client) {
    const result = await client.db("NameOfYourDb").collection("NameOfYourCollection").updateOne(
        { "_id": "UniqueId1", "items.item_name": "my_item_one" },
        { $set: { "items.$.logic": false, "items.$.last_seen": 4000 } }
    );

    console.log(`${result.matchedCount} document(s) matched the query criteria.`);
    console.log(`${result.modifiedCount} document(s) was/were updated.`);
}
```

I have found this original piece of code here bellow:

[MongoDB Node.JS driver: create, append, and update documents with arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59879070/mongodb-node-js-driver-create-append-and-update-documents-with-arrays)

Of course some modifications are required.

Comment: That code is demonstrating 3 different operations.  What is it you're trying to do that these don't help with?

Comment: Can these 3 operations be merged? Why do I have to call 3 of them, couldn't I just run 1?

Comment: Those are 3 very different operations, if you don't know whether your database contains the document you are referencing, and you don't know if the array in the stored document contains the element you want to update, you could use the pipeline form of the update command with the upsert option.